# IE11's Document Mode drop down is disabled. Is there any way to enable it?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 (more specifically, 11.0.9600.16384) on a fresh Windows 8.1 install. For whatever reason the Document Mode drop down in the browser's developer tools is disabled, regardless of which page I visit.

[image: Example Image]

When clicked, the [image: icon] icon opens https://www.modern.ie/en-us/f12 which doesn't mention anything about the Document Mode drop down being disabled.

I'm well aware that IE's Document Mode is deprecated and shouldn't be used to debug production issues for older browsers, but I've had no issues with doing that in the past and I'm currently on a limited bandwidth connection and don't really have the option to download a large OS image to test using a virtual machine.

1. Why is my Document Mode disabled?
2. Is there anything I can do to enable it again?

Comment: This is handled by a group policy on your network.  The reason its "disabled", is because its set by a group policy.  Its the only explanation that make since, since there are GP, for compatibility settings within IE

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think that's the reason as my account hasn't been modified. My old OS (also Windows 8.1) could access the Document Mode just fine.

Comment: I am running a newer version of IE11 and its enabled on my machine.  Have you checked if a group policy is at fault?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure where this would be set within the group policy settings.

Comment: Adding your website to the list in Compatibility View Settings (you can find it in browser's Tools menu) may also fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems the issue was that the version of IE11 I was using wasn't fully up to date. The drop down is enabled in 11.0.9600.17498. No idea why it was disabled in 11.0.9600.16384 but hey, it's working now.